# Setting focus on first field of a pop up edit form in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid in pop up edit mode. First field of the pop up form is auto complete widget. I want to give focus on it whenever the pop up form pops up. I tried to do this in different way as

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({ 
    editor: 
        function(container, options) { 
            $('<input id="item_code_focus" name="' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoAutoComplete({ 
                    -----
                    -----
            }).focus()
        }
});
```

But it is not working. Please help me?...

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use the **[edit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#edit)** event of the Grid.

```
    edit:function(e){   
         e.container.data('kendoWindow').bind('activate',function(e){
            $('#autocomplete').focus();
         })

    },
```

EDIT: Actually you should use the Window activate event to call focus. Here is [example](http://jsbin.com/edamuj/342/edit). @OnaBai calling focus when using the edit does not make the input to lose focus - actually the animation causes this behavior.

Comment: I think that if you set `focus` while the popup window is still being opened, you loose focus. Did you try it? I think that you need to do the trick of setting a timeout that then sets the `focus`. Something like `setTimeout(function() { $("#item_code_focus", ev.container).focus(); }, 1000);`

Comment: Actually you can, you did it! Try that same example but click on top right corner (small arrow on the right of "auto-run JS") for opening it in "live preview" mode. Seems that JSBin does something in the background :-D

Comment: Ok nice, thank you for pointing this out. Actaully the proper way to call the focus will be to use the activate event of the window. I have updated my post above.

Comment: I agree that the solution is using the `activate` event on the `popup` window, Should not be this the code shown and not the reference to JSBin? I was about to edit your answer but I prefer that you do it since it is you answer.

Comment: Actually thinking about this solutions and coming from Real Time systems I see a problem: the window is created before start executing `edit` handler but we are not binding `activate` until `edit` has started executing. Theoretically we can miss the activate if for some reason it ends opening before getting to `bind`. Since the animation is pretty slow, it should not happen BUT the experience says that if something might go wrong then will go wrong! Anyhow +1